# how to use put null,is null check, all checks in SQL query dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, null

I need to update a portion in a pl/sql.
In that pl/sql we are inserting data in a temporary table based on the given filters.

Now currently are inserting data when

```
 select blah where given_timestamp is null
```

But now what I need to do is to check some cases before inserting data into temporary table. And based on that checks I have to give conditions in where clause as mentioned below:

```
1. where some_timestamp is null
2. where some_timestamp is not null
3. where some_timestamp is null or given_timestamp is not null
```

My Problem:
I could not find a logic to fit in here in such a way that a where condition should work in all these three cases, so that Its should not break the existing functionality. (The current sp itself is too much big)

What I tried:
I tried to take out the data in a param:

```
if(condition 1) then
set param_timestamp=(select some_timestamp from xyz where some_timestamp is null);
elsif (condition 2) then
set param_timestamp=(select some_timestamp from xyz where some_timestamp is not null);
else
set param_timestamp=(select some_timestamp from xyz);



select blah where some_timestamp in (param_timestamp)
```

The problem with this approach is that it is failing when i am checking for nulls.
I tried few other approaches also bu t all of them are creating a problem when checking for nulls.

Any help would be appreciated.

All I need to do is to give this condition dynamically (for null, not null,all)

Comment: `set param_timestamp=select s...` is not legal PL/SQL

Comment: What's the error?  Try Select some_timestamp into param_timestamp...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hi, I have edited the qsn, could you please have a look at it again

Comment: @FionaT hi,the problem is some_timestamp has null, not null values. I can do what you have suggested n above all it is going to give me the same thing which I have mentioned above. But how I am going to use it again for required functionality.

Comment: What you are showing is pseudo code rather than PL/SQL. And still: there is *one* variable called param_timestamp. One variable can hold *one* value. So how can you select *all* timestamps or just *some* timestamps into it? That should be *one* timestamp, say the minimum non-null timestamp for instance. And `select some_timestamp from xyz where some_timestamp is null` will return nulls. All that doesn't make sense.

Comment: some_timestamp is a column? And given_timestamp is also a column? Or a PL/SQL variable?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner some_timestamp is a column and given_timestamp is a varaible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your query will only differ in whether to select null and non-null values you can use variables for that. Have two variables for "select null timestamps" and "select non-null timestamps" and set them according to the desired rules. Don't use BOOLEAN but a numeric type instead, so you can use them in your SQL query. (Oracle SQL doesn't know BOOLEAN.)

```
v_sel_nulls integer; -- 1 = yes , 0 = no
v_sel_nonnulls integer; -- 1 = yes , 0 = no


if (condition block 1) then
  v_sel_nulls := 1;
  v_sel_nonnulls := 0;
elsif (condition block 2) then
  v_sel_nulls := 0;
  v_sel_nonnulls := 1;
else
  v_sel_nulls := 1;
  v_sel_nonnulls := 1;
end if;

select ...
into ...
from ...
where (v_sel_nulls = 1 or some_timestamp is not null)
and (v_sel_nonnulls = 1 or some_timestamp is null);
```

Comment: Ur solution really worked. I spent almost three days to find out a solution. But could not found it.. Seriously amazing.. Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a flag with NVL function? and evaluate it, something like

```
select nvl(some_timestamp, '01-01-1900') from xyz where some_timestamp;
```

Comment: I dont have to check particular timestamp. I only have to check for NULL, NOT NULL, ALL values based on some given condtion